# Writing HashMap contents to the file

Tags: java, hashmap, java-8, nio, java-stream

I have a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>`. I write its content to the file, so each line of it contains `hashmapKey:::hashmapValue`. This is how I do it now:

```
List<String> mLines = new ArrayList<String>();
mHashMap.forEach((key, value) -> mLines.add(key + DATA_SEPARATOR + value));
Files.write(mOutputPath, mLines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

I very doubt that I need to copy entire `HashMap` to the list of strings, I am sure it will give me performance issues when working with big amounts of data. My question is: how can I write `HashMap` contents to the file using Java 8 avoiding copying values in another list?

Comment: You put the code that does the writing inside your lambda or iterate over the map using  `Map.entrySet`

Comment: you don't really need a DATA_SEPARATOR as int has a fixed size

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The simplest, non-copying, most “streamish” solution is

```
Files.write(mOutputPath, () -> mHashMap.entrySet().stream()
    .<CharSequence>map(e -> e.getKey() + DATA_SEPARATOR + e.getValue())
    .iterator());
```

While a Stream does not implement `Iterable`, a lambda expression performing a Stream operation that ends with calling `iterator()` on the stream, can be. It will fulfill the contract as the lambda expression will, unlike a Stream, produce a new `Iterator` on each invocation.

Note that I removed the explicit `UTF-8` character set specifier as `java.nio.Files` will use `UTF-8` when no charset is specified (unlike the old io classes).

The neat thing about the above solution is that the I/O operation wraps the Stream processing, so inside the Stream, we don’t have to deal with checked exceptions. In contrast, the `Writer`+`forEach` solution needs to handle `IOException`s as a `BiConsumer` is not allowed to throw checked exceptions. As a result, a working solution using `forEach` would look like:

```
try(Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(mOutputPath)) {
    mHashMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
        try { writer.write(key + DATA_SEPARATOR + value + System.lineSeparator()); }
        catch (IOException ex) { throw new UncheckedIOException(ex); }
    });
} catch(UncheckedIOException ex) { throw ex.getCause(); }
```

Comment: Note that (while it's sane assumption) it's not specified that `Files.write` traverses the `Iterable` only once.

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: It’s also within the specification if the JRE reuses the lambda instance (assuming that it captures the same `Map` instance) on multiple executions of this code. That’s another reason to ensure correctly producing a new iterator on each invocation.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply avoid using a `List<String>` by directly writing out the lines to disk using e.g. a `Writer`:

```
    Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream(new File(mOutputPath)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    mHashMap.forEach((key, value) -> writer.write(key + DATA_SEPARATOR + value + System.lineSeparator()));
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
```

Comment: You should use [try-with-resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html).

Comment: Besides that, this solution doesn’t work as `IOException`s potentially thrown by `Writer.write` must be catched (which will dramatically complicate the lambda expression)…

Comment: I omitted a try-catch or finally environment intentional as it is just a code snippet showing how to do it an not a full-featured program.

Comment: @Robert: you should really read the linked article. A try-with-resource statement doesn’t need a `finally` clause and is, in fact, shorter than your code.

Comment: @Holger I know try-with-resource. As it is equal to a try -finally block I did not mention it separately.

Comment: If you know it, you should know that it allows to omit the explicit `close()` invocation (the `flush()` is obsolete anyway), so *again*, it would make your code *simpler*, so there is no reason not to use it in an answer. Your code is more complicated than necessary while failing to ensure safe closing. Besides that, it is *not* equal to closing in a `finally` block, there is a fundamental semantic difference.

Comment: Is there a way to append a file with stream.

Comment: @Jagesh Maharjan That is independent of the stream API. The `FileOutputStream` has a constructor which takes a `boolean` as second argument. If you set this to `true` it will append the data to an existing file.

Comment: @Robert, I was supposed to Comment on the previous Answer but commented here. Sorry for the ambiguity. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could map the entries of the map to a string and write them to a `FileChannel`. The additional methods simply do the exception handling so the stream operations become more readable.

```
final Charset charset =  Charset.forName("UTF-8");
try(FileChannel fc = FileChannel.open(mOutputPath, StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW)) {
    mHashMap.entrySet().stream().map(e -> e.getKey() + ":::" + e.getValue() + "\n")
            .map(s -> encode(charset, s))
            .forEach(bb -> write(fc, bb));
}

void write(FileChannel fc, ByteBuffer bb){
    try {
        fc.write(bb);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

ByteBuffer encode( Charset charset, String string){
    try {
        return charset.newEncoder().encode(CharBuffer.wrap(string));
    } catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

`HashMap` implements `Serializable` so you should be able to use standard serialization to write hashmap to file.

*Example:*

```
HashMap<Integer, String> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

//Adding elements to HashMap

try {
    FileOutputStream fos =
            new FileOutputStream("example.ser");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(hmap);
    oos.close();
    fos.close();
}catch(IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```