# How to read File to HashMap, update HashMap, and then update File

Tags: java, file, hashmap

I'm trying to create a login in system where there is a file that stores all the initial userNames and passwords. These informations will then be written into a HashMap for comparing events like if userName exists or if userName matches password.

When there is a newly registered account, I want to update the HashMap which will then write the new account info into the file. How can I update the file and prevent dupilicating userInfo?

The following is my code to read file to HashMap

```
public static void HashMapFromFile() {
        Map<String, String> userInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();
        BufferedReader bfr = null;
        try {
            File f = new File("userInformation.txt");
            bfr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            while(true) {
                String line = bfr.readLine();
                String[] parts = line.split(" ");

                String userName = parts[0].trim();
                String pwd = parts[1].trim();

                if(!userName.equals("") && !pwd.equals("") && !userInfo.containsKey(userName)) {
                    userInfo.put(userName, pwd);
                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("I/O Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        finally {
            if (bfr != null) {
                try {
                    bfr.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                };
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Just write the `HashMap` contents to the file. Refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527177/writing-hashmap-contents-to-the-file